# Assigning NSString value to a UI Label text through segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

So I am trying to have a string @"Welcome%@!" be tagged to my pointer *name so if a user inputs there name on the UI Label text it can be segued to the next page and also have the greeting "Welcome" be attached to the name. My code goes as follows:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"setName:"]) {
    if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setName:)]) {
        NSString *name = self.nameTextField.text;
        [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector
         (setName:) withObject:name];
    }
}
}
Next Page “Second View Controller.m” :
```

@interface SecondViewController ()
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
    @implementation SecondViewController

```
-(void)setName: (NSString *)name
{
    _name = name;
    self.nameLabel.text = self.name;

}
```

Can anyone show me how to input a string so it will be tagged along with the (NSString *)name

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about [Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html). Below is my answer:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"setName:"]) {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setName:)]) {
            NSString *name = self.nameTextField.text;
            SecondViewController *secondCtrl = [segue destinationViewController];
            [secondCtrl setName:name];
        }
    }
}
```

In your SecondViewController:

```
@interface SecondViewController () 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel; 
@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
    _name = name;
    self.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", self.name];
}

@end
```

Comment: I attempted that but I continue to get a signal SIGABRT error, do you know why?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the SIGABRT error, however the example you posted did not attach the Welcome string.

Comment: wow okay I got it! Thank you so much Shamsiddin. I failed at first because I didn't insert the NSString section under the -(void)viewDidLoad section I had underneath the above setName:(NSString *)name. Thanks a ton for the tips though!